# Can't connect to SSAS server -- "Element 'return' was not found. Line 5, position 2."

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssas, connectivity

I'm trying to access an SSAS server from SSMS v17.4 (2017).

I'm using Windows Authentication.
I know the credentials are correct and can actually connect successfully from Visual Studio 2015.

However in SSIS, with the connection string (note my credentials are not my actual Windows login but an assumed identity/ different username I think).

```
Server type: Analysis Services
Server name: myServerName.com\myCatalog
Authentication: Windows Authentication
```

and then

```
Data source = myServerName.com;
User ID = myUserID;
Password = myPassword;
Initial Catalog = myCatalog;
Provider=MSOLAP.7;
Format=Tabular;
```

I know the connection string is registering as correct because when I put in a wrong/ dupe password, a different error results. The system knows the password is correct.

I'm getting the error

```
Element 'return' not found. Line 5, position 2. (System.Xml)
```

So I'm not sure what's going wrong here. What is the best client to connect to an SSAS environment to view Cube definitions and MDX queries etc? What could be going wrong here where the connection otherwise works fine in Visual Studio 2015 from the same computer?

I heard it could be .dll files of some sort. No idea where to begin here.

Comment: Error seems like connection timing out. Try to change the connection time-out value in the connection options to a higher value.. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/94c5f8a5-62ae-42a2-b8ef-c371238d7619/cannot-connect-to-analysis-services-from-ssms?forum=sqltools

Comment: I saw that as well. Didn't do anything. If I set the connection properties in the tab or manually in the connection string. Very odd.

Comment: What version of SSAS and SSIS? Is your SSIS package deployed to the SSIS Catalog? If so, what is the sensitive information encrypted setting for the package?

Comment: You mean the SSAS environment where the OLAP cubes are located? No idea what version. I would need a Dev person with existing access to determine that. The 'creator' is long gone. Others have access and can help me, but I am unsure. How would I determine that without connection/ login ability? SSIS --- this is an ETL process --- as far as I know, it's an optional tool, and not necessarily the ETL required to build and configure SSAS cubes (in this case the SSAS cubes are built atop an Oracle database). And altogether, unsure how this related to me actually connection to the SSAS thing via SSMS